# How to change transform of a RealityKit OrbitAnimation already in progress?

Tags: animation, transform, realitykit

There are many questions about transform, but this is unique because it involves a transform within an OrbitAnimation.

My question is simply: how do I make my OrbitAnimation slowly widen?

Which is another way of saying: When I start the animation, I set the x,y,z of the orbiting entity to be offset from the entity which is being orbited.

**startTransform: Transform(translation: [0, *1*, 0]),**

But I can only do that with the "startTransform" (which I set to be translated to 0,1,0 from the entity which is being orbited.) But how do I update the transform after that? For example, if instead of y being "1", I would like it to *slowly expand to "2"*?

(Without the animation stopping, being reset, etc.)

Thank you.

```
    func startAnimation() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            let orbit = OrbitAnimation(duration: 10, axis: [0, 1, -5], 
startTransform: Transform(translation: [0, 1, 0]), 
bindTarget: .transform, repeatMode: .repeat)

            let animation = try! AnimationResource.generate(with: orbit)
            //entity!.playAnimation(animation)
            dragonSphere!.playAnimation(animation)
//            dragonSphere!.availableAnimations.forEach { animation in
//                dragonSphere!.playAnimation(animation.repeat())
//            }
        }
    }
```